# Вставить заготовленный текст в VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Я устал каждый раз писать `console.log()`, есть ли какой то плагин или уже готовое решения, что бы нажать определенную комбинацию и вставился нужный, заранее заготовленный текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=whtouche.vscode-js-console-utils

Вот, (cmd+shift+l) и вводится console.log :)

Comment: Балдеж, то что нужно :)